# Why does the ready event not fire if the function is async

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, dom-events, document-ready

```
// Does not fire
$(document).ready(async function()
{
    alert("im ready");
});

// Does fire
$(document).ready(function()
{
    alert("im ready");
});

// Annoying fix
$(document).ready(function()
{
    (async() =>
    {
        alert("im ready");
    })();
});
```

Other events such as clicks, and input do support the async function.
The only one that doesn't is the ready event.
Any ideas why?

Comment: `$(document).ready(async function() {});` works fine. Please check for any error in your console.

Comment: @BadPiggie — It doesn't work when I test it

Comment: @Quentin which version? I tested with the latest jQuery.

Comment: I was testing with 3.1.0 since that was the latest on the dropdown menu in jsBin. Testing with 3.6.0 and it works. It must have been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Yeah. I tested on StackOverflow's snippet with `3.3.1` it works fine.